# Does anyone know of any online converters for my issue?

Tags: html, converters

I have recently taken over a new website but when I get the source code its unescaped in JavaScript like this:

```
%3C%21DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A
```

Unfortunetly I do not know what the %XX thingys are called so I cant find a converter to convert it back into HTML.

Thanks in advance. (sorry for the poor explaining I just don't know how to explain this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Or in any JS console:

```
unescape('%3C%21DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A');
```

And, to be clear, that is URL encoding and has nothing to with javascript.  It replaces any character that may be reserved or cause problems with urls.

Answer (score 1):

Decoded it's

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

Drop it in here to see: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: yes i know I just copied a little bit as an example... I have huge lines of this stuff I need converted.

Comment: You can drop it in the converter I listed.